# Firebase orderByChild issue

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase

Hi I'm building an app using ionic and firebase and here is my firebase model:

```html
{
  "users" : {
    "D972XU" : {
      "8b91cc58-a962-4753-abd9-896b8a9418d5" : {
        "email" : "jim@aol.com",
        "house_key" : "D972XU",
        "username" : "jim"
      },
      "8ea6537a-6385-4797-8fc3-62e9e5f06ac6" : {
        "email" : "george@gmail.com",
        "house_key" : "D972XU",
        "username" : "george"
      }
    },
    "V1OVU5" : {
      "f4f283c0-f503-4d50-8af8-7a9ad592ca74" : {
        "email" : "john@yahoo.com",
        "house_key" : "V1OVU5",
        "username" : "john"
      }
    },
    "YOKSPN" : {
      "891bb612-4666-4095-be62-87c81f65c895" : {
        "email" : "jeff@gmail.com",
        "house_key" : "YOKSPN",
        "username" : "jeff"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the model, users are stored under a randomly generated string. My problem is that I'm trying to find the value of the string using this code in the firebase docs:

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key() + " was " + snapshot.val().height + " meters tall");
});
```

My version:

```js
app.factory('fireBaseData', function($firebase) {
  var usersRef = new Firebase("https://mynextapp.firebaseio.com/users");
  return {
        ref: function() {
            return ref;
        }
      };
});

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, fireBaseData) {
  fireBaseData.usersRef().child(authData.uid).orderByChild("email").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.key());
          });
  });
```

According to the docs, you shouldn't need to know the value of the specific dinosaur/string to access its details. However, the code doesn't work for me. Help please?

Note that the child nodes of /users, D972XU, V10VU5 and YOKSPN are randomly generated.

Comment: A few things: In the question you mentioned that the users are stored under a randomly generated string, but in the function that loads it, you are referring the authData.uid. Is it a randomly generated string or the uid? Also, if you know the key, which is authData.uid, then well, you know the key. Are you trying to get the key based on email being equal to an specific email? If so, your function isn't right for that. Finally, the firebase example in the question iterates over ALL of the child dinosaur nodes and prints their name and height so that's not what you want.

Comment: Sorry I should've specified; the authData.uid is part of an authWithEmail function. And yes I'm trying to find the house_key based on a specific email, and I know the code isn't quite right for what I want but I'm getting no results whatsoever from it.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a node (key) based on a child value, here's the code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mynextapp.firebaseio.com/users/D972XU");
ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("jim").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

or for mail

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mynextapp.firebaseio.com/users/D972XU");
ref.orderByChild("email").equalTo("jim@aol.com").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

In this case, your /users node has direct children that are randomly generated and the data you are after is within those children. Because of that a query can't 'reach' your data as it's too deep. Even a Deep Query needs more info to work. So you have:

> /users/random_node_name/uid

so this

> fireBaseData.usersRef().child(authData.uid)

won't work because it leaves out the node between users and the authData.uid.

But - the solution is provided in the structure. The randomly generated node name is also stored within the data (a duplicate), which may eliminate the need to use it as a key.

Moving your data up one level is a solution so change the structure to:

```
    {
      "users" : {
          "8b91cc58-a962-4753-abd9-896b8a9418d5" : {
            "email" : "jim@aol.com",
            "house_key" : "D972XU",
            "username" : "jim"
          },
          "8ea6537a-6385-4797-8fc3-62e9e5f06ac6" : {
            "email" : "george@gmail.com",
            "house_key" : "D972XU",
            "username" : "george"
          },
          "f4f283c0-f503-4d50-8af8-7a9ad592ca74" : {
            "email" : "john@yahoo.com",
            "house_key" : "V1OVU5",
            "username" : "john"
          },
          "891bb612-4666-4095-be62-87c81f65c895" : {
            "email" : "jeff@gmail.com",
            "house_key" : "YOKSPN",
            "username" : "jeff"
          }
        }
    }
```

As a side note, the structure I suggest is 'traditionally' how a /users node would be structured in Firebase. It has proven to be consistent, expandable and maintainable (and makes using Rules to secure your data much easier).

Your original structure is going to be a bear to make Rules work with.

Comment: Hi Jay, I've tried these methods before and several variations but nothing happens unfortunately.

Comment: Whoops. I mis-read your structure. I thought you had uid's stored within your users node. It's actually one more level deep, within the D972XU node. So just change your ref to mynextapp.firebaseio.com/users/D972XU. I corrected my answer (and tested the code)

Comment: Oops, I probably should've specified that the 6-character strings are randomly generated so a static url won't work. I've updated my JSON again to give a better example.

Comment: Gotcha. You're not going to get there from here. BUT... There's a solution, see my updated answer.

Comment: Ah I see, I suspected I would have to make a change in the structure. Thank you so much for your help, Jay.